# How to get rid of the left and right margins in 966 grid?

Tags: html, css, frameworks, grid

When the viewport size is 784 x 741  there is a left and right margin applied to the box that I want to get rid of. I know how to get rid of the "white space" at the top, but it's the "white space on the sides that I can't get rid of. Does anyone know how to eliminate the white space so the header stretches the full width of the browser viewport? My codepen is below.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/mike316/pen/xOKXKm)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid_12">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a><li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1>ALIEN</h1>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use a 996 for that then. The whole point of the 996 (and 960) grid is to create a container with a maximum width of 996px.

Comment: So there's really no way to eliminate that when the browser window is re-sized? I understand when the viewport is all the way open, I was hoping that when the viewport is smaller, I could get rid of the margins on the side. What other framework would you recommend? I wanted to learn 996 because it has excellent browser support.

Comment: You can override any of the CSS in your 996 grid that you want. That is the beauty of CSS. All I'm suggesting is that if your header is just one big column anyway, why apply column styles to it?

Comment: Just for the practice I guess. There maybe a customer that would want the header to extend all the way on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you searching for **the quickest way** to make the header full width of the screen, you have to add another one class to two divs (let's call it *'full-width'* for example). The result should be something like this:

Html

```
<div class="container full-width">
    <div class="grid_12 full-width">
    <!-- another code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.full-width {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

This class will **reset** all **paddings/margins** and set **width** to **100%** for every (or almost every) element with this class. After this, little margins (8px) will remain, this is margins of `body` element. If you want to get rid of them too, just include in your css this code:

```
body {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

This is the quick way that mustn't break another css a lot. But if you're wondering what properties should be changed (you **can change them manually** instead of adding our *'full-width'* class), have a look:

You can change the lines *105 and 106, 221 and 222* to

```
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
```

You also need to reset paddings on lines *327* and *328*

```
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
```

Don't forget to set `width: 100% !important;` to `container` and `grid_12` `div`s! In order not to break the remaining css, add new class(es) or ides.

Comment: That looks perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can change margins for **any media query** to any value you want (or delete them by adding `margin: 0;` property). If you want to clear margins for all elements, just apply `* {margin: 0;}` somewhere at the top of your css (just in case, let me remind that the `*` selects all elements).

You also can change `margin-top`, `margin-right`, `margin-bottom` and `margin-left` properties separately.
Choose any media query you want and override `margin` property for it.
If this does not solve the problem as you want, you have to solve this by changing 
*position* and *width* of elements.

Comment: Okay. I'll have a look. There's a lot of CSS going on though, would know exactly which margins I should change? I have a feeling it will be the. grid_xx. And thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll send you full answer below soon.

Comment: Okay. I've been practicing on the grid for awhile, and have not figured it out yet.